# Using a custom ConfigMap with Quarkus with packing-type 'fast-jar' does not work

Tags: kubernetes, quarkus, configmap, smallrye

### The problem

After changing the `quarkus.package.type` to `fast-jar`, the application instances on our Kubernetes cluster could no longer read a mounted ConfigMap.

```sh
2022-02-17 14:39:45,155 WARN [com.example.MyStartupService] (main)
    Config param is not defined and might be missing: foo.bars
```

Locally there is no problem with the configuration, but we also do not mount it - just have a static `application.yml`. Before this change everything worked fine, we can directly track it to the `quarkus.package.type`.

### Our Setup

First and foremost: We do not use a `application.properties`, but a `application.yml` (utilizing `quarkus-config-yaml`).

We are using Quarkus `2.7.1.Final`.

##### Java Code

```java
@ConfigMapping(prefix = CONFIG_PREFIX)
public interface FooBarConfigMapping {

    String CONFIG_PREFIX = "foo";
    String CONFIG_NAME = "bars";
    String CONFIG_PARAM = String.join(".", CONFIG_PREFIX, CONFIG_NAME);

    @WithName(CONFIG_NAME)
    List<BarConfig> barConfigurations();

    interface BarConfig {
        @WithName("name")
        String name();
    }
}
```

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyStartupService {

    @Inject
    FooBarConfigMapping fooBarConfigMapping;

    @Transactional
    void startup(@Observes @Priority(2501) StartupEvent event) {
        if (fooBarConfigMapping.barConfigurations().isEmpty()) {
            LOGGER.debug("Config param is not defined and might be missing: " + FooBarConfigMapping.CONFIG_PARAM);
        }

        // do something with fooBarConfigMapping.barConfigurations()
    }
}
```

##### Deployment

Our application-config.yaml (ConfigMap):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: application-configmap
  # ...
data:
  application.yml: |
    foo:
      bars:
        -
          name: A
        -
          name: B
        -
          name: C
```

Our deployment.yaml (Deployment):

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  # ...
spec:
  # ...
  template:
    # ...
    spec:
      # ...
      containers:
          # ...
          volumeMounts:
            - name: application-config
              mountPath: /config
      volumes:
        - name: application-config
          configMap:
            name: application-configmap
```

### Misc

1. I can't find any good information what might have changed between `legacy-jar` and `fast-jar` i.r.t. reading out the config. Maybe it is related to the different structures (as shown [here](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2021/04/08/build-even-faster-quarkus-applications-with-fast-jar#step_2__package_the_applications_to_compare_formats)). For me this might be the likeliest source of the error.

   1.1. I tried to change the mount-path from `/config` to `/usr/local/apps/config` (following this [SmallRye ConfigMap example](https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-config/blob/main/examples/configmap/.kubernetes/configmap-app.yml#L42)), but to no avail.

   1.2. I also tried to rename the mounted file from `application.yml` to `application.yaml`, but same outcome.

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me. Mind opening an issue on our Github?